# heroicons implentation for vue for other icon libraries?

Tags: vue.js, icons

I like how heroicons is implemented in Vue, which is a simple

```
// page.vue
import { MapIcon, MapPinIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/24/outline';

<MapIcon /> <MapPinIcon />
```

but there is not a lot of icons to be used as i need

and there is many libraries like [Oh,Vue-Icons](https://oh-vue-icons.js.org/) that has all kinds of icons and [Material Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons) but there implementation is so tedious which is like this

```
// main.js
import { OhVueIcon, addIcons } from "oh-vue-icons";
import { FaFlag, RiZhihuFill } from "oh-vue-icons/icons";
addIcons(FaFlag, RiZhihuFill)
app.component("v-icon", OhVueIcon);

// page.vue
<v-icon name="fa-flag" />  <v-icon name="ri-zhihu-fill" />
```

which requires me to define every icon I will need manually from this point on by both writing in import and in addIcons

or like

```
// page.vue
import MenuIcon from 'vue-material-design-icons/Menu.vue';
import RailwayIcon from 'vue-material-design-icons/Railway.vue';
defineComponent({
    MenuIcon,
    Railway
})

<menu-icon /> <railway-icon />
```

which takes more space and still manual

is there any library like heroicons in this manner or a way to handle it? I am used to heroicons and never realized how the process is done outside of it so I am surprsied by how tedious it is